# How to host an ExpressJS app with namecheap cPanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cpanel, namecheap

I am trying to host my website, written with ExpressJS, using namecheap's cPanel, along with cloudflare, but can't seem to figure out how to deploy it. There isn't an option for a Node.js application so I resorted to using my cPanel's terminal to host it. Here's my basic ExpressJS code that I used for testing:

```js
const express = require('express')
const https = require("https")
const fs = require("fs")
const app = express()

const cert = fs.readFileSync("./cert.crt")
const ca = fs.readFileSync("./ca.ca-bundle")
const key = fs.readFileSync("./private.key")

let options = {
    cert: cert,
    ca: ca,
    key: key
}
let server = https.createServer(options, app)

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

server.listen(8080, 'shared ip', () => { console.log("Hosting!") });
```

Whenever I go to mydomain.com the index.html file gets served like normal, but when I go to mydomain.com/test I get a 404 not found. When looking at the GET request my site seems to be getting my server's IP with port `443` instead of `8080`. Then when I go to mydomain.com:8080/test I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. I'm not totally sure how to fix this.

Comment: "There isn't an option for a Node.js application" are you sure it's supported?

Comment: @Phix According to https://features.cpanel.net/topic/nodejs-hosting support for Node.js was added in v80 and I'm using v88

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is the standard TCP port that is used for website by default
try changing to `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, () => { console.log("Hosting!") });`
or `server.listen(443, 'shared ip', () => { console.log("Hosting!") });`

Comment: When doing those ports I keep getting `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use`